# how to upgrade dart to 2.10.2 in MacOS

Tags: dart

Today(2020/10/27) I want to upgrade my dart to version `2.10.2`, then I use this command:

```
~ ⌚ 9:58:16
$ brew upgrade dart
Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart 2.9.3 already installed
```

why could not upgrade to `2.10.2`? must I install dart from sources?

Comment: Have you run `brew update`?

Comment: no, I have not run this command.@nthnchu

Comment: Try `brew update && brew upgrade dart`. Does that work?

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the command `brew update` **before** you upgrade with `brew upgrade`. What the `upgrade` command does is refresh the list of packages, their versions, and where to download. In other words, it runs `git pull` for each tap you've tapped, and the core tap. It's also similar to `sudo apt-get update` on linux systems with apt. In short, just run **`brew update && brew upgrade dart`** and it should work. If that doesn't work for some people, it might be that you have to install from source to get this version, as the question pointed out.